# C++ class member initialization & constructor definition

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello I started learning C++ and at the moment i'm testing member initializers I have written this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
private:

    string p_name;
    string p_surname;
    int p_age;

};

Person::Person(string name, string surname, int age) : p_name(name), p_surname(surname), p_age(age)
{


}

Person::~Person()
{
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int value) : m_value(value)
    {
    }
private:
    int m_value;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However in Person class I get the following error

> Error 1   error C2511: 'Person::Person(std::string,std::string,int)' :
>   overloaded member function not found in
>   'Person'  c:\users\syd\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp 19  1   ConsoleApplication1

Also in the second class there is no error. If I'm not mistaken I'm declaring the constructor in the wrong way in Person class and the interpreter thinks I'm overloading a missing method? I'm sure an error like this might be silly to most of you but if someone could explain in simple terms what I'm doing wrong I would be grateful.

Comment: Your prototype also needs parameters. `Person(string name, string surname, int age);`

Comment: The constructor you've declared in `Person` is the default constructor (`Person();`) but the definition you've provided takes 3 arguments, hence the error. Within the class body, change the constructor declaration to `Person(string, string, int);` And the word you're looking for is *compiler*, not *interpreter* :)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm used to web development hence the interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration of `Person()` does not match the definition of `Person(string name, string surname, int age)`.

In your class declaration, change person to

```
public:
  Person(string name, string surname, int age);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however would something like this be enough?  Person(string,string,int) without the specific variables, because in VC it works, just wondering if it is bad practice or smthing

Comment: @Syd Yes you can have a prototype without the variable name. The syntax is correct.

Comment: I think it's more of a personal preference - I use VC as well and I like having intellisense tell me the names of the variables for a given function as I'm writing code. It's helpful when the code base is very large.

Comment: It's good to use the names as it is a form of documentation of how the class is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a prototype of your constructor (the one with parameters) in the class Person instead of the current prototype which has no parameters

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(string name, string surname, int age);
    ~Person();
private:

    string p_name;
    string p_surname;
    int p_age;

};
```